# Прикрепление файлов к сообщению

Tags: yii2

Я сформировал форму обратной связи.Стоит задача, дать возможность потенциальному клиенту прикрепить к сообщению файл.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это реализовать? Желательно дать ссылки, либо написать код реализации.

В документации лишь прикрепление файлов из папки проекта, т.е. если я рассылаю сообщения и хочу прикрепить файл.
Я уже задавал данный вопрос [viewtopic.php?f=19&t=44257](http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=44257), но так и не смог его реализовать, не совсем понял.

Comment: Исправьте ссылку на форум.

Answer (score 1):

1) Подгружаете файл 
https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide-ru/input-file-upload/

2) создаете запись о подгруженном файле.

3) отправляете ссылку на файл на сервере вместе с письмом получателю обратной связи.

Comment: Можно прикреплять файл сразу к письму, если это будет удобнее.